# how to change textview according to the change in the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

i am new at android development .I am making a quiz with 10 questions (10 activities). there is another activity(name "Lost") which opens on wrong answer and contains a TextView(telling the score up-till now) according to the question number (activity number). I AM NOT ABLE TO SET THE TEXTVIEW ACCORDING TO THE ACTIVITY NUMBER. for example , if a person loses at 5th ques the activity(Lost) open and set the textview to 50 , and when person gives wrong answer at 9th ques the activity(Lost) opens and  set the textview to 90. i dont know how to do this .. help me

this is my code-

that is 1st ques (similar code is for other questions)  -

```
    RadioGroup rg1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        rg1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.level1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg1){
        case R.id.r11:
        RadioButton ans=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.r11);
            ans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    Intent myintent=new Intent(view.getContext(), Level2.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent,0);

                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.r12:
            RadioButton ans1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.r12);
            ans1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    Intent myintent=new Intent(view.getContext(), Lost.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent,0);

                }
            });

        case R.id.r13:RadioButton   ans2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.r13);
        ans2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent myintent=new Intent(view.getContext(), Lost.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,0);

            }
        });

            break;
        case R.id.r14:RadioButton   ans3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.r14);
        ans3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent myintent=new Intent(view.getContext(), Lost.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,0);

            }
        });
            break;
        }
    }
```

this is  "Lost" activity code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lost);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        Button home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Home);
        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent myintent=new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivityQuiz.class);
                startActivityForResult(myintent,0);

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lost, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

plz tell me how to do that....

Answer (score 1):

In your level activity add an extra to your intent

```
        Intent myintent=new Intent(view.getContext(), Lost.class);
        myintent.putExtra("score", LEVEL_SCORE);
        startActivityForResult(myintent,0);
```

where LEVEL_SCORE is the int score associate to your level.
In lost activity you can get the score doing that :

```
        Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        int score = myIntent.getIntExtra("score");
```

You can now display score in the textView.

Comment: i applied this , but this works only for one level(question). the text view has to change according to other questions also.

Comment: should i use a switch case whose arrgument changes according to the activity number or name?

Comment: Maybe you can pass more information in the intent...
You can for example pass String and use getStringExtra() in the started activity

Comment: and you can eventually switch case to build the textview according to the receveid data

Comment: then can u plz tell me the method through which i can use switch , like public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) is for RadioGroup. what's for TextView ?